# Database normalization in django

Tags: django, database, django-models

I need an optimally normalized database structure to achieve the following requirement.

**`models.py`**

```
class Learning_Institute(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='courses_taught')
    institute = models.ForeignKey(Learning_Institute, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='courses')
```

I need the **instructor** field in the **Course** table to be limited to the set of **users** in **Learning_Institute** instead of all the users in the system.
How do I achieve this on the DB level?

Comment: Sorry, it is nove very clear what you are asking.  Can you be more clear?

Comment: Please avoid underscore in class names in Python. Use `LearningInstitute` instead of `Learning_Institute`. Check [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for coding conventions in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility in Django to achieve this in your model class. The option that can be used in `models.ForeignKey` is called [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to).

First I'd very strongly recommend to rename the field `user` in the class `LearningInstitute` to `users`. It is a many to many relation, which means an institute can have many users, and a user can perform some work in many institutes.

Naming it correctly in plural helps to better understand the business logic.

Then you can adapt the field `instructor` in the class `Course`:

```
instructor = models.ForeignKey(
    'User', # or maybe settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    related_name='courses_taught',
    limit_choices_to=~models.Q(learning_institute_set=None)
)
```

This is not tested and probably will need some adjustment. The idea is to get all `User` objects, where the field `learning_institute_set` (default related name, since you haven't specified one) is not (the ~ sign negates the query) `None`.

This has however nothing to do with normalisation on the database level. The implementation is solely in the application code, and the database has no information about that.

As suggested by @TreantBG, a good approach would be to extend the class `User` and create class `Instructor` (or similar). This approach would affect the database by creating an appropriate table for `Instructor`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can limit in the model itself.

One of the things that you can do is on form save to have validations using form clearing methods [like so](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

And you can create a check that does something like this:

```
def clean_ instructor(self):
    instructor = self.cleaned_data['instructor']
    if instructor.type != "instructor":
        raise forms.ValidationError("The user is not instructor!")
```

Another option is to create another User object that will inherit User and you can call it InstrcutorUsers

I have used [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) to extend the user model in django

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's suitable for your scenario but changing the relations slightly may achieve what you want.
Removing the many to many for User and create a concrete association model for it, will
at least make sure the Course can only have users that also are instructors, by design.

Consider the following model structure:

```
class LearningInstitute(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class InstituteInstructor(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together=('user','institute')

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    institute = models.ForeighKey(LearningInstitute, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(InstituteInstructor, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

1. You have LearningInstitutes
2. A user can be an instructor with a related institute, a User can only be related to the same institute once
3. A Course can only have an instructor (and by that also the related institute)
4. Design can easily be extended to let Courses have multiple instructors.

By design the Course can only have users that are also instructors.